# Select conversations of user but not the user

Tags: sql, laravel

I have a database like

```
User
  UserName
  UserId

Chat
  ChatId
  ChatSubject

ChatUser
  Chat_ChatId
  User_UserId

ChatMessage
  Chat_ChatId
  User_UserId
  Message
```

I have the current user id in a variable like : $userId

What i want is find the Chat_ChatSubject an the UserName of the other person in the chat, so i can create a list of conversations where i show the username of the other person and the subject

What i have :

```
$conversations= Chat::
        Join('ChatUser', 'Chat.id', '=', 'ChatUser.User_UserId')
        ->Join('User', 'User.UserId', '=', 'ChatUser.User_UserId')
        ->Select('Users.UserName', 'Chat.Subject')
        ->OrderBy('ChatUsers.Chat_ChatId','asc')
        ->GroupBy('Chat.ChatId')
        ->get();
```

The result of this is a list of Chats but it contains not always the name of the other person. What i want is that User.UserName is the username of the other person so not my own.

(There are always 2 ChatUsers in one Chat

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the relations set up in your models...

```
$conversations = User::find($userId)
                    ->chats()
                    ->with(array('users' => function($query) use ($userId){
                        $query->where('id', '!=', $id);
                    }))->get();

foreach($conversations as $conversation){
    $conversation->ChatSubject; // get subject
    $conversation->users; // get users collection (current user excluded)
}
```